# Как функция передаётся в качестве параметра?

Tags: c++

```
string GetDB()
{
    return "Show DB";
}

void Show(string(*fun)())
{
    cout << fun() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Show(GetDB);
}
```

Не совсем могу понять как в шестой строке функция передаётся в качестве параметра. 
Как я понял, код `string(*fun)()` должен обьявлять указатель `fun`, которому я могу потом присвоить ссылку на функцию (вроде `fun = GetDB`). Но почему мы строку присваивания пишем в аргумент функции, и почему функция `GetDB` при попадании в этот аргумент копирует свой адрес в указатель `fun`?

Comment: переменная **fun** локальная. Действует как временная переменная внутри функции **Show**. Вы можете много раз вызывать функцию **Show** с *разными* аргументами (функциями). *Поучите обычный Си сначала.*

Comment: Для начала почитайте об *указателях на функцию*. Это поможет вам разобраться.

Comment: *"ссылку на функцию"* Скорее адрес функции. Ссылок в этом коде нет. *"Но почему мы строку присваивания пишем в аргумент функции"* А как это связано с указателями на функции? Вот у вас есть `void foo(int x)`. Вы можете сделать `x = 1` внутри функции, и вы так же можете написать `foo(1);`. Это то же самое. *"почему функция GetDB при попадании в этот аргумент копирует свой адрес в указатель fun"* DrawnRaccoon правильно говорит. Функции обычно автоматически преобразуются в указатели на себя, так что `fun = GetDB` равно `fun = &GetDB`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ой да ладно, тут на хабре вчера статья была, так там тоже ни одной ссылки в примерах, но автор упорно называл указатели ссылками, или списком ссылок вот такое `int* a[]`. Мне кажется, это просто люди, которые пришли из других языков, Java там, или ещё каких, где нет сырых указателей

Comment: @vegorov Я просто неверно выразился с ссылкой и уже понял ошибку. Я изучаю с++ как первый язык чуть более 2 недель, поэтому часто путаюсь в понятиях.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string(*fun)()` - это *указатель* на функцию, а не ссылка на функцию.

Тип "функция" в языках С и С++ является *неявно приводимым* к соответствующему типу "указатель на функцию". Поэтому когда вы пишете

```
Show(GetDB);
```

язык С++ неявно преобразует аргумент `GetDB` типа `string()` к требуемому типу параметра `string (*)()`. Если вам так больше нравится, вы можете явно сформировать указатель на функцию

```
Show(&GetDB);
```

Оба варианта полностью эквивалентны.

Симметричным образом, при вызове через указатель `fun` вы можете напрямую применять оператор `()` к указателю `fun`, как в вашем оригинальном коде, а можете предварительно явно разыменовывать указатель `(*fun)()`. Оба варианта полностью эквивалентны.